# Typescript type mapping to expect an object where every property is of a given type

Tags: typescript

In typescript I have an interface of type X. I have a method that expects an object with an arbitrary number of properties, but every property must be of type X. For example both of these would be valid to pass as parameters:

```
interface IJays {
    jim: X;
    jone: X;
    jan: X;
}
```

and

```
interface IBees {
    bill: X;
    bob: X;
    betty: X;
}
```

but this would NOT be a valid type to pass as a parameter:

```
interface ISees {
    claude: X;
    carol: boolean;
    clem: number;
}
```

In this case, the name of the properties are important, too (they get used in the processing).

It would be great if I could use a different data structure, but this is the structure that is coming from some API. I don't have a finite list of all the interfaces, either. As the project grows, there will be any number of interfaces that follow this pattern.

Currently, I have this property typed as "any", but I would really like to have it as a specific type to prevent future errors (this is the kind of thing that is prone to errors in the future).

Is there a way to specify this as a type in typescript? Essentially, an arbitrary object where each property of that object is of a specific type? Perhaps using the new [Mapped Types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#mapped-types) feature?

Comment: What kind of information do you gain by knowing all the values are the same type without knowing what that type is or what properties you'll have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see it you have two options:

(1) A function with a generic value type:

```
interface IJays {
    jim: string;
    jone: string;
    jan: string;
}

interface IBees {
    bill: string;
    bob: string;
    betty: string;
}

interface ISees {
    claude: string;
    carol: boolean;
    clem: number;
}

function fn<T, V>(o: { [key in keyof T]: V }) { /* ... */ }

let a: IJays = { jim: "jim", jone: "jone", jan: "jan" };
fn<IJays, string>(a); // fine

let b: IBees = { bill: "bill", bob: "bob", betty: "betty" };
fn<IBees, string>(b); // fine

let c: ISees = { claude: "claude", carol: true, clem: 3 };
fn<ISees, string>(c); // error
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20IJays%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20jim%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20jone%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20jan%3A%20string%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20IBees%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20bill%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20bob%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20betty%3A%20string%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20ISees%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20claude%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20carol%3A%20boolean%3B%0A%20%20%20%20clem%3A%20number%3B%0A%7D%20%0A%0Afunction%20fn%3CT%2C%20V%3E(o%3A%20%7B%20%5Bkey%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3A%20V%20%7D)%20%7B%20%2F*%20...%20*%2F%20%7D%0A%0Alet%20a%3A%20IJays%20%3D%20%7B%20jim%3A%20%22jim%22%2C%20jone%3A%20%22jone%22%2C%20jan%3A%20%22jan%22%20%7D%3B%0Afn%3CIJays%2C%20string%3E(a)%3B%20%2F%2F%20fine%0A%0Alet%20b%3A%20IBees%20%3D%20%7B%20bill%3A%20%22bill%22%2C%20bob%3A%20%22bob%22%2C%20betty%3A%20%22betty%22%20%7D%3B%0Afn%3CIBees%2C%20string%3E(b)%3B%20%2F%2F%20fine%0A%0Alet%20c%3A%20ISees%20%3D%20%7B%20claude%3A%20%22claude%22%2C%20carol%3A%20true%2C%20clem%3A%203%20%7D%3B%0Afn%3CISees%2C%20string%3E(c)%3B%20%2F%2F%20error))

But as you can see, you'll have to specify the generic constraints when invoking the function as the compiler won't be able to infer them.
If you don't want to do that then options #2.

(2) Have different functions for each type:

```
function fnString<T>(o: { [key in keyof T]: string }) { /* ... */ }
function fnNumber<T>(o: { [key in keyof T]: number }) { /* ... */ }

let a: IJays = { jim: "jim", jone: "jone", jan: "jan" };
fnString(a); // fine

let b: IBees = { bill: "bill", bob: "bob", betty: "betty" };
fnString(b); // fine

let c: ISees = { claude: "claude", carol: true, clem: 3 };
fnString(c); // error
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20IJays%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20jim%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20jone%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20jan%3A%20string%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20IBees%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20bill%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20bob%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20betty%3A%20string%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20ISees%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20claude%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20carol%3A%20boolean%3B%0A%20%20%20%20clem%3A%20number%3B%0A%7D%20%0A%0Afunction%20fnString%3CT%3E(o%3A%20%7B%20%5Bkey%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3A%20string%20%7D)%20%7B%20%2F*%20...%20*%2F%20%7D%0Afunction%20fnNumber%3CT%3E(o%3A%20%7B%20%5Bkey%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3A%20number%20%7D)%20%7B%20%2F*%20...%20*%2F%20%7D%0A%0Alet%20a%3A%20IJays%20%3D%20%7B%20jim%3A%20%22jim%22%2C%20jone%3A%20%22jone%22%2C%20jan%3A%20%22jan%22%20%7D%3B%0AfnString(a)%3B%20%2F%2F%20fine%0A%0Alet%20b%3A%20IBees%20%3D%20%7B%20bill%3A%20%22bill%22%2C%20bob%3A%20%22bob%22%2C%20betty%3A%20%22betty%22%20%7D%3B%0AfnString(b)%3B%20%2F%2F%20fine%0A%0Alet%20c%3A%20ISees%20%3D%20%7B%20claude%3A%20%22claude%22%2C%20carol%3A%20true%2C%20clem%3A%203%20%7D%3B%0AfnString(c)%3B%20%2F%2F%20error))

Here the compiler can infer the generic constraint, but you'll need to have different functions per type.